# git compare doesnt show any difference

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

My Master branch history looks like below

```
CommitID      Comments       Time
--------      --------       ----
Commit9       Comment9       9am
Commit8       Comment8       8am
Commit7       Comment7       7am
Commit6       Comment6       6am
Commit5       Comment5       5am
Commit4       Comment4       4am
Commit3       Comment3       3am
Commit2       Comment2       2am
Commit1       Comment1       1am
```

Then, I created branch b1 from commit id `Commit5`. When I compared b1 with master branch, no differences are showing up. Why?

Update: `git diff master --name-only` shows the files modified as expected. 
When I tried to compare or merge my branch to master, I received message master is up to date with all commits from b1

Update: @papanito Repo can be seen at -https://github.com/nagiahraj/git-compare-not-working
The data in foo.txt file in "master" branch and "branch-from-commit3" branch are different. But that difference is not shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: How do you do the compare? Please give more specifics

Comment: I compared branches using github as in https://help.github.com/en/articles/comparing-commits-across-time . I used visual studio 2017 to create new branch from the commit id https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/history/vs-view-commit-details.png?view=azure-devops

Comment: Can you specify the commands that were used in creating a new branch and then when you were comparing current branch with master? Or if you used VS for it, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Post edit: Again you haven't provided the commands you were to create a new branch or how you are merging to master?

Comment: I didn't use command. I used IDE visual studio 2017 to create new branch from the commit id just like in the screenshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/history/vs-view-commit-details.png?view=azure-devops

Comment: `git merge` does not mean "make branches the same". So it's no surprise that `git merge` can say "up to date" while `git diff` says "these don't match". Merge means *take changes since the last common ancestor, and add them, recording the new common ancestor".

Comment: You are using github for the compare, do you have a link to the project?

Comment: git diff branchX...master 

Try this. You should see different number of commits between two.

Comment: @PunitVara git diff master...branch-from-commit3 didn't show any difference. But when I change the command to git diff branch-from-commit3...master, noticed the changes. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github compare does the same as `git diff master...branch-from-commit3`, which is the following: It looks for the first commit that is reachable from `commit3`, but not from `master` and then displays the diff between that commit and `commit3`. In your case there is no such commit, so the difference is empty.

Why does it behave that way? Because this way you get all the changes on your branch that have not yet been merged to master. So it's kind of like a merge preview.

`git diff master..branch-from-commit3` on the other hand compares the contents of `commit3` with the contents of the tip of master, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following. You branched from `commit3` and then added an another commit to the master branch. So your master branch is 1 commit ahead your feature branch. So following what [@Chronial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758345/chronial) told

> Github compare does the same as `git diff master...branch-from-commit3`, which is the following: It looks for the first commit that is reachable from `commit3`, but not from `master`and then displays the diff between that commit and `commit3`. In your case there is no such commit, so the difference is empty.
>
> `git diff master..branch-from-commit3` on the other hand compares the contents of `commit3` with the contents of the tip of `master`, which seems to be what you are looking for.

[image]